# Max number of nested \input in LaTeX/Beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

When using the beamer documentclass, it looks like the third level of nested input is ignored:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{body}

body.tex:
\begin{document}
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
\end{document}

file2.tex:
\input{file21}
```

The content of file21.tex is ignored with documentclass beamer, but correctly inserted if I use a documentclass article, for example.

Has anyone seen something like this?

Comment: Works for me.  Can you post a minimal example, with a `\listfiles` in your preamble, and the output list of files?

Answer (score 2):

Do you perhaps use the `[ignorenonframetext]` option ?
If so, `\input` is taken as nonframe text and ignored.

You can do `\mode<all>{\input{file}}` to force the input to work in the presentation mode.
You will need to start the included file with `\mode*` to start ignoring non frame text again.